# 16.04 Failing to boot due to Bluetooth / Network Manager Wait Online?

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot, network-manager, bluetooth

**What machine do I have?**

Dual boot machine with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

**What was the last thing I did before the issue?**

Tried updating bluetooth packages.. tried installing pulseaudio, and required/recommend packages by following [this guide](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/multimedia/pulseaudio.html)

**Why?**

I was experiencing bluetooth audio issues, and learnt that my issues should be resolved with a later version of pulseaudio.

**What is happening now?**

Upon booting, the splash screen shows the following failure messages

- Failed to start Raise network interfaces
- Failed to start Login Service
- Failed to start Accounts Service
- Failed to start Modem Manager
- Failed to start Thermal Daemon Service
- Failed to start Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
- Failed to start Network Manager
- Dependency failed for Network Manager Wait Online

Then, hangs there until about 10 minutes later the screen goes black, indefinitely.

[Splash screen output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67ap9.jpg)

**What have I done to try resolve it?**

1. I booted to recovery mode, and tried to use the dpkg and fsck
   options, even enable networking options.. all resulted in the
   message: *Continuing will remount your / filesystem in read/write
   mode....* Upon selecting yes, nothing happens, I can type in the
   black space below the message, but it just hangs here, I can't
   execute commands, I can't escape, forced to manually reboot.
2. I created a Live CD, got onto "try ubuntu", and followed a guide to
   run boot-repair. No success. [Here is the output log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5dMJBYJHn7/)
3. I went back onto the Live CD, "try ubuntu", mounted my Ubuntu
   installation, used chroot onto the mounted location, purged and
   reinstalled the network manager, pulseaudio and bluetooth packages.
   No success.
4. I come to you for help.